# Joomla: can't find code of something

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I need to change some information in my block which is in sidebar. I found what I need in temples/mytemplate/index.php file. But here I can see only such tag (_RSS_NEWS):
[enter image description here](http://puu.sh/mx1tY/6616d4cd77.png)

**How can I find code of _RSS_NEWS for example?**

_RSS_NEWS is example, I need another thing. But the main question what is it? And how to find it?

```
<?= _VARIABLE ?>
```

I tried to find what I need in database, and tried to open a lot of files and seatch for this tag. But all my efforts were unsuccessful...

I'm using very old Joomla. But my problem doesn't here.

Please help me!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

do you use IDE **NetBeans**??i has hint or autocomplete,and its perfect.i like it more than dreamweaver
 you shouldn't ( never)  try finding methods,varrible  with test and errors.
netbeans does this work **easly conditionally the function is defined.**
also you should for developing web you should extentions **Webdevoloper , firebug**
for easy in devoloping.

goodluck